# Angular js - cache a rootScope param and it's value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, rootscope

Hey how do i cache for x time this simple object that i set via $http ( $rootScope.config.app_genres)?

```
 $http.get($rootScope.config.app_ws+'get/genres',{},{cache:true}).success(function(response) {
    $rootScope.config.app_genres =  response;
  });
```

i just would like to cache it to not repeat everytime the http request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in [$http documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http), you can provide your own cache object instance through the cache configuration option.

Here's a `$cacheFactory` where I override the `put` method so that the cache gets cleared after `TIMEOUT`. Note that this only works for one URL. I'll leave making this timer cache object generic as an exercise for you.

```
function Ctrl($scope, $http, $cacheFactory, $timeout) {
  var timedCache = $cacheFactory('myCache'),
      TIMEOUT = 5000,
      cacheTimer = null;

  timedCache._put = timedCache.put;
  timedCache.put = function (key, val) {
    console.log('caching', key);

    $timeout.cancel(cacheTimer);
    cacheTimer = $timeout(function () {
      console.log('clearing cache for', key);
      timedCache.remove(key);
    }, TIMEOUT, false);

    timedCache._put(key, val);
  };

  $scope.request = function () {
    $http.get('/echo/json', {
      cache: timedCache
    })
    .success(function (data) {
      console.log('received', data);
    });
  };
}
```

Here's the fiddle with this working: http://jsfiddle.net/sirhc/jvLPX/

Answer (score 4):

H i , ( hoping Angular has something built in, that others may add but )

I guess we could  assign it to a new variable

```
$rootScope.dataCache = $rootScope.data;

$rootScope.cacheTimer = 50000;
```

Your websites application always reading from $rootScope.dataCache and a routine to check and/or auto update when CacheTimer had elapsed, to recall the server side and re assign.

?

Comment: so dataCache and cacheTimer are natives? :P

Comment: nope, they sound like they could be, no, just regular variable names of your choosing.

Comment: thanks man , can you please provide a working example also for the community? :)

Comment: given enough time today, maybe. Let me know if this didn't help I will delete it if so and leaves the question "unanswered", and or post up how far you got using this principle.

Answer (score 3):

I use this code to cache templates

```
$http.get(/*URL*/, {cache: $templateCache})
    .success(function () { ... })
    .error(function () { ... });
```

but maybe this one will be more of what you want to do
https://coderwall.com/p/40axlq

Answer (score 3):

You could use cache busting for your requirement. Lets say if you want to cache only for x seconds. The you add a cache busting query parameter with value

`Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / (x * 1000))`

The request would look like

```
$http.get(url,{cacheBuster: Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / (x * 1000))},{cache:true})
```